# Is it possible to use correctly navigation keys (hotkeys plugin) with search plugin ("show_only_matches": true)

Tags: javascript, jstree

I`m trying to use navigation through jsTree and search plugin with "show_only_matches" parameter. But when I navigate through the tree using up and down arrows hidden nodes can be selected, but I would like to walk through "visible" nodes.

Comment: Can you set up a demo on jsFiddle?

Comment: It took some time. Please look at http://jsfiddle.net/G789k/25/ If you type "Bas" in input field and click on filter button. When try to use "arrow down" key. On first key down event, root Basic folder will be selected. On second key down event, login folder will be selected.(but it is hidden!!!). On third key down event, Basic folder (which is in Basic folder) will be selected.

Comment: I see. Should be easy enough to override the arrow keys to skip hidden nodes. (The other option is to modify the jstree source but I would avoid that if you can.) I'll work on that now and get it up for you...

Comment: already added an issue https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/158 . Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this jsFiddle for the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/G789k/27/

I did it just on the down key, so you'll need to adapt it for up. Almost exactly the same thing -- just change `_get_next` to `_get_prev`.

Here is the relevant part of the code, FYI:

```
"search" : {
  "case_insensitive" : true,
  "show_only_matches": true         
},
"ui" :{
  "select_limit" : 1,
},
// overriding hotkey
'hotkeys': {
  'down': function() {

      // most of this stolen from jstree.js source
      var o = this.data.ui.hovered || this.data.ui.last_selected || -1,
          node = this._get_next(o);

      this.hover_node(node);

      // call self if selected node is hidden
      // note: this is a somewhat dangerous (and deprecated) way to do recursion.
      // ultimately, it would be better if your down function was
      // defined elsewhere and called here as needed.

      if ( node.length && node.is(':hidden')) arguments.callee.call(this);

      return false;
  }   
}
```

I also think the default functionality – navigating to hidden nodes – is undesirable and the jstree dev should fix it. Consider submitting it as a bugfix/request to him.